# Angular Universal app keeps loading problem

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I was about to set up SSR for my Angular 7 app using Angular Universal. I followed the official documentation (https://angular.io/guide/universal). I reach the point, where I need to run `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`. After that I see in terminal: `Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000`. No errors both in terminal and browser. The page just keeps on loading.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to check, when you navigate to `http://localhost:4000` in your browser you have no errors? Not even after waiting a few minutes for any kind of timeout that would tell you more?

Comment: @David just the response that localhost didn't send any data

Comment: Can you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It has something to do with unsupported properties like window, document, setTimeout. It is VERY frustrating that the debug gives you no help at all.